# Log in as LinkedIn - Xamarin OAuth - Cancel button event?

Tags: oauth, xamarin.forms, linkedin-api

I am developing application in Xamarin for iOS and Android. I want to implement log in as LinkedIn (using OAuth 2.0), but I have a problem when I click to Cancel button on LinkedIn authenticate form. I got dialog error (see picture). I know that I had to specify cancel callback url when I registered app on LinkedIn, but I am confused what is callback url since I use Xamarin page navigation? I only want to go back to RootPage when I click to Cancel button. Is there any event?

[image: Dialog error]

Comment: is there any way to remove this popup